# regexp replace between some slashes

Tags: php, regex

I need help with  write regex pattern for replace my variable.

Input data
strings for parse:
/hello/world/1111/2/3/4
/hello/world/2222/2/3/4
/hello/world/3333/2/3/4
/hello/world/3333
/hello/world/1111

replace value = some

Out 
/hello/world/some/2/3/4
/hello/world/some/2/3/4
/hello/world/some/2/3/4
/hello/world/some
/hello/world/some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$out = preg_replace("#^/(\w+)/(\w+)/\d{4}(/.*)?$#", "/$1/$2/some$3", $in);
```

This will do the correct replacement for you, here a short explanation:

```
^         start of line
(\w+)     >1 literals
\d{4}     exactly 4 digits
(/.*)?    anything starting with / or nothing at all
$         end of line
```

Answer (score 0):

If they all have four digits in the part you want to replace, just do this:

```
$input = preg_replace("/\d{4}/", "some", $input);
```

Comment: Once another id reaches 4 digits, they will also be deleted. `/hello/world/1111/2/3/4444` => `/hello/world/some/2/3/some` instead of `/hello/world/some/2/3/4444`

Comment: but it dosnt work with /hello/world/1111
and digits can be unlimited

Answer (score 0):

If the input number is always four digits, then

```
$input = preg_replace("~/\d{4}(/.*)?$~", "some$1", $input);
```